# Font Engine Multiplatform

Tags: opengl, graphics, fonts, directx, 2d

I want to develop a font engine so my GUIs look identical in all platforms. I've come to a pickle here as I want to make sure I approach it in the most productive angle, yet an angle that gives me the ability to implement as much as possible on my own (for learning purposes).

I just want an outline of how I should do it, maybe give some example paths that I can follow.

I was researching bezier curves but I don't think it was a good idea because I don't see how drawing only lines can scale up properly making the letters empty. I was also looking into implementing it with ttf font files but didn't see upscaling and downscaling being dependent on the image size as a practical thing, mainly because of memory consumption.

Also provide some advantages/disadvantages with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

The curves define the boundary of the font glyph, from which you determine where to fill color. It is just like how a solid polygon is defined by line segments on its boundary.